# Ever since Mac battery drained (and shut down), Rails app can't post anything to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-connection

My Mac battery ran out while I was running a Rails 3 app, and after I plugged my Mac in and restarted it, I tried running my Rails app's development server (using mysql for the database). Upon trying to update something, I got "Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2))". It turns out that I get this every time I try to post or update now.

There doesn't seem to be any actual problem with the database. I can create new rails apps that work with sqlite, mysql, or postgres, but this old app, which worked fine before, can't work with any of the databases, and I get the same "Connection refused - connect(2)" error no matter which I try. I've never seen this error before, I should note. Also, I don't know that it would matter, but I'm running Rails 3.0.1 on Ruby 1.9.2.

Does anyone know what went wrong? Something went sideways, but I'm at a loss, losing hair and sleep...

Comment: "every time I try to post or update now"... Any chance that a read-only flag was set on that db? You're getting denied on write operations only...

Comment: Have you tried the app with a fresh database?

Comment: Half-fixed the problem... I had been using the sunspot_rails gem and had a hunch that got screwed up from the crash/restart, so I commented out 'sunspot_rails' in the gemfile and all references to it in the models and controllers, and I'm now able to post again. I'll see if I can get sunspot up again. Not sure what the problem is, but I guess the worst scare is over.

Comment: I think the problem with write operations is because when you write to a table, sunspot tries to index it, and the sunspot connection isn't working. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the related gems, and stopping and starting sunspot. Not sure what can be done about that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thing just happened to me. Im sure you've already solved this by now, but this worked for me; try this in your terminal:

rake sunspot:solr:start

rake sunspot:solr:stop

rake sunspot:solr:start

Starting sunspot then killing the process didn't fix the problem. When I stopped it through a rake task then restarted it, it did.

Comment: thanks. after the problem, i switched to using postgreSQL and searching with the texticle gem, which has worked fairly well. i might go back and try solr again at some point.